# Adding Subdirectories to Load Path

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Rather than individually specifing each subdirectory in my plugins directory I want to be able to automatically load them, to that end I included the following to my .emacs file:

```
(let ((base  "~/.emacs.d/plugins/"))
      (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))

require 'rinari
require 'yasnippet
```

Unfortunately the above results in: `File error: Cannot open load file, rinari`

Anyone know what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're so close...

```
(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/plugins/"))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

`normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` works off the current directory, which you can set via the variable `default-directory` - not `base` like you tried.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `default-directory` was a special variable.

Answer (score 4):

You might investigate the role of the `subdirs.el` files during startup.  It is a good way get subdirectories into your `load-path`.

For example, much of the default load-path arises as a consequence of the files discovered by this command:
`find /usr -name subdirs.el`

Comment: Ah, nice! Yes, see `C-h i g (elisp) Startup Summary` and `C-h f normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` and and `C-h f normal-top-level-add-to-load-path`, and look at the usage of those in existing `subdirs.el` files.