# Add functionality to emacs major mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wrote an elisp function and a few `defvar`'s that I use to interactively add boost unit test macros. Since it is used with Boost, it will only be needed in c++-mode. Currently it is in my init file so it is always loaded in every mode.

How do I make it so this functionality is only available in c++-mode, i.e. as if I added it to the major mode itself.

Comment: It really depends on what you're talking about.  Do you want the code to be lazily loaded?  Do you want the commands bound to keys only in C++ mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the code you wrote to only be loaded when needed, you can put it into a file of its own (say `boost-unit-test.el`), and from your `.emacs` you could add:

```
(eval-after-load "cc-mode" '(require 'boost-unit-test))
```

Note, this assumes the file is in your [`load-path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322246/adding-subdirectories-to-load-path) and has `(provide 'boost-unit-test)` as one of the lines.

Now, once this file is loaded, those variables and those commands are defined globally, and that's just the way Emacs is.  This is no different than if you left the code in your `.emacs` file.  And, either way, it will only be loaded/evaluated once (unless you force it to load multiple times - but you have to work to do that).