# emacs: load-path and require (cannot open load file)

Tags: emacs, elisp, require, load-path

I've got `"Cannot open load file"` error at `(require 'org-mime)` while load-path variable seems to be all right:

```
load-path is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is
("/home/alexey/.emacs.d/elpa/bbdb-20130526.1945" "/home/alexey/.emacs.d/elpa/org-mime-20120112" "/home/alexey/.emacs.d/elpa/smex-20130421.2153" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/site-lisp" "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp" "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp
...
```

Curiously, the remedy looks like this (.emacs):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-mime-20120112")
```

It isn't merely ugly: it's dysfunctional, because the versioned path is subject to change. But why the error?

Comment: if you are using elpa system, you need first do (require 'package)
  (package-initialize) else emacs won't even see the load path. (i think. )

Comment: It's probably a problem of ordering in your .emacs, which causes the `(require 'org-mime)` to be run before the `load-path` is properly set.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting issue that happens when you load a file that requires another file -- the file that is required must be loaded in chronological order before the next file.  For example, if B requires A then A must be placed higher up in chronological order so that when B loads, A is already loaded.

I've had really good luck with this type of setup.  Most files end with el or elc, so I'm not sure why you want to load a file with a different or no extension, but it is certainly possible to do that if you want.

```
(let* ((root.d "~/") (sub-dir (concat root.d ".emacs.d/")))
    (load-file (concat sub-dir "init.el"))
    (setq load-path
(append `(,root.d ,sub-dir
    ,(concat sub-dir "elpa/yasnippet")
) load-path)))
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322246/adding-subdirectories-to-load-path), or so I gather. I can't understand your remark about extensions: all the targets are *.el so far.

Comment: lawlist: If B requires A (such that it calls `(require 'A)`) and A is not already loaded, then it will be loaded at that time (provided it is in the load path, etc...). The call to `require` ensures that the required library is loaded before it is needed. You don't need to do anything manually. (Or if that's not what you meant, you may wish to clarify...)

Comment: Ah - - - thank you -- I've been adding a lot of `el` manually when trying out new things -- I'll trying setting up a temporary load path for my testing and see if that helps -- there was recently an example of a circular A needs B, and B needs A ,to create a product of C and the load path might have fixed it.  Always a pleasure to learn new tricks . . . :)

Comment: @Alexey Orlov -- thank you -- looking at the numeric digits, I just assumed it was a file instead of a directory -- I stand corrected.